# What is off-topic about asking if it's unprofessional to wear headphones while at work?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question here was put on hold because it was 'off-topic'.

[Is it unprofessional to listen to music while at work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33045/is-it-unprofessional-to-listen-to-music-while-at-work)

Why is this?

This question is....

- About professionalism not about company regulations
- Not specific to my company but in the workplace in general
- About the workplace
- Not about me specifically

So why was it marked as off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

A question asking if something is professional is by definition primarily opinion based. The responses will differ depending on culture, from corporate to federal. Everyone will have a different opinion, and none of these opinions can be backed with any factual data.

Instead, The Workplace SE works best for questions about a real problem you're facing. As an example, there's [How can I make wearing headphones at work more acceptable?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7533/how-can-i-make-wearing-headphones-at-work-more-acceptable)  This question has a clear, actionable goal in mind, and the answers provide details on what a person can do who wishes to make this more acceptable in their workplace.

If you can edit with a clear goal in mind, we can look at reopening, but I suspect your question would become a duplicate of the one I linked. You should check out that post and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: So the question is not "off topic" but rather "open to interpretation"

Comment: Almost the entire site is opinion-based, including your suggested re-wording. http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes I looked at the first page of the most popular questions - all are opinion-based. Mathoverflow can play the "opinion-based" card, Workplace by and large can not.

Comment: @coburne - It is a very thin line that our site rides, which is why taking a deep breath, re-reading the on-hold question, and finding a way to slightly edit it can help bring it more in-line with being backed, not by unsubstantiated opinion, but opinion backed by facts and references. That's really the key: Will the question evoke answers backed by facts and references.

Comment: @Ghaag - I recommend reading [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). It does a good job explaining, via the six guidelines for a good subjective question, how questions can be worded to attract fact-based answers. Opinions are fine, [as long as they can be backed up](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others). Hope this helps clarify.